# Patronage of Saint Thomas the Apostle?

Tags: science, atheism, thomas-apostle, patron-saints, skepticism

Is Saint Doubting Thomas the Patron Saint of any of the following:

1. Rational Theology
2. Science
3. Skepticism (religious [atheism] and others)

*Deus Magnus Est*

Comment: Thomas said to Jesus, 'My Lord and my God'. Why do you tag this question with 'atheism' ? Voted to closure as 'opinion-based'.

Comment: Because skepticism - doubt(ing) Thomas - is the *granum* of atheism.

Comment: _Sicut granum sinapis_ (grain of mustard seed) - just a grain of faith will move mountains. And just a trace of leaven (of hypocrisy) will mar the entire lump.

Comment: He is a might have been a saint in the religion of Confusionism but soon backslid into certainty based on tangible evidence.

Answer (score 2):

He's the patron saint of the blind, craftsmen, geometricians, theologians ([1](https://www.stapostle.org/st-thomas-church-parish-history/our-patron-saint-thomas/)), architects ([2](https://christianapostles.com/st-thomas-the-apostle/)), and sometimes is thought of as a patron saint of India.

St. Albertus Magnus is the patron saint of science. I can't find any official patron saint of skeptics, but St. Augustine and St. Thomas are at least proposed unofficially. I can't find a patron saint of "rational theology" per se, but St. Thomas Aquinas, the patron saint of students and universities, who did foundational works of rational theology, is at least close.

Answer (score 2):

**Patronages of Saint Thomas the Apostle?**

St. Thomas the Apostle is considered the Patron Saint of doubters, **skeptics** and cynics.

> Because of his period of disbelief, St. Thomas has become the patron saint who resolves the qualms, misgivings and reservations of doubters, skeptics and cynics. - [A patron saint for doubters](https://www.catholicherald.com/article/columns/a-patron-saint-for-doubters/)

If he is the patron saint of skeptics, logic tells us that he is the patron saint of [skepticism](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/13516b.htm) at the same time.

[St. Albertus Magnus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albertus_Magnus) is the patron saint of scientists, natural sciences, medical technicians and philosophers.

Gold Mass anyone?

> Gold Masses are usually Votive Masses in honor of St. Albert the Great (patron saint of natural science), and use the readings and propers for his feast day (November 15).  Many such Masses are celebrated on the feast day of St. Albert or near it.  However, almost any time during the school year is possible. (A Votive Mass in honor of St. Albert can be said on days other than November 15 subject to liturgical norms. See sections 375 and 376 of the liturgical norms) Other particularly appropriate dates for a Gold Mass are the Feast day of St. Thomas Aquinas (January 28) and the Optional Memorial of St. John Henry Newman (October 9), where the readings for those Memorials would be used. - [Gold Masses](https://catholicscientists.org/gold-masses/)